# IE9 user-agent issue on redirect

Tags: security, session, internet-explorer-9

I am using user-agent validation on the session. If user-agent is changing we are deleting the session.

But I am facing problem with IE9 with google oauth  redirect.

When IE9 is hitting our site,  IE is having valid IE9 user-agent

So user-agent is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
```

but after redirection from user-agent is becoming

```
 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

so I logic for session validation is failing in this case. 
Is there any way with ie9 to force IE to fallback to IE9 user-agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a user agent check doesn't make your session more secure.  There is no condition in which an attacker will have a session id and not have a user-agent.  Your security system is identical to this: `http://domain/?is_hacker=No`.  If you want to make your session more secure you should enable the cookie secuirty flags and remove this bullshit check.